# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errMsg'

Tags: python, spss

This is a python program that interacts with SPSS. I didn't write it, but I'm trying to get it to run. It is from 2008.

```
import os,sys
from errMsg import errTable
from errMsg import StrError
from os.path import exists
import ConfigParser
```

Comment: I believe this is telling you that it can't find a file called errMsg.py. Does it exist on your computer?

Comment: The module is in this path, which I am using. sys.path.insert(0,r'C:/Program Files/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/26/Python/Lib')

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Changing the environment to python 2 fixed everything.